# Get BestBuy seller's orders using Commerce API

Tags: best-buy-api

How can I fetch order details of particular seller using BestBuy API? I read the documentation on https://developer.bestbuy.com/ but it seems there ain't anything related to order management using API.

**Commerce API** https://developer.bestbuy.com/documentation/commerce-api

> Basic Commerce API Functionality
>
> - Look up product availability, delivery dates, shipping costs prior to    order submission
> - Create orders including Store Pick Up, Ship to Home    and Home Delivery
> - Look up order information
> - Modify/Cancel an Order

- Where is the documentation for order look up and modification?
- Does BestBuy allows us fetching/updating order information using API?

Answer (score 0):

The Commerce API requires more specific access than the regular Best Buy public APIs. You will need to apply for a specific Commerce API key and become a Partner to have access to the Commerce API. If you are not yet a Partner, please send an email to developer@bestbuy.com to request an invite. Further documentation can be found once you have access as a Partner.

Thank you.